# Unable to see the coverage folder in the Azure DevOps for Angular Application

Tags: angular, azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage

When I am running the test script to check the coverage in the local `ng test --browsers=headless-mode --code-coverage --watch=false` I can see there is a folder which contains the lcov.info under the path coverage/appname/. I am using it send the results to SonarQube. but when I ran the same task in the Azure Devops somehow the folder is not getting created. I ran a shell script to get the contents of the pipeline but unable to see the folder it has only test results folder and inside that there is no lcov.info file.
can someone help me on what is going wrong.

I am trying to integrate sonarque to the application. while running locally I run the code coverage command and run sonar command which gets push properly but not in the pipeline its unable to find the lcov.info

Here is the sonar properties

```
sonar.host.url=#{sonarqubeHost}#
sonar.login=#{sonarLogin}#
sonar.projectKey=testUI
sonar.projectName=testUI
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/coverage/lcov.info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my mistake. The coverage folder sits at the top. so, updated the sonar report path worked.

```
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/appname/lcov.info
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)